# How do I convert this recursive implementation of finding nodes between two levels in a binary tree to an iterative version?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

This is how I build a Binary Tree:

```
class BinaryTree():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.key = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

t2 = BinaryTree(20)
t2.left = BinaryTree(8)
t2.left.left = BinaryTree(4)
t2.left.right = BinaryTree(12)
t2.left.right.left = BinaryTree(10)
t2.left.right.right = BinaryTree(14)
t2.right = BinaryTree(22)
```

This is my recursive function that returns nodes between two levels:

```
def find_nodes_between_two_levels(tree, high, low, currentLevel=1, output=None):
    if output is None:
        output = {}

    if tree is None or currentLevel > low:
        return

    if currentLevel >=high and currentLevel<=low:
        if currentLevel not in output:
            output[currentLevel] = [tree.key]
        else:
            output[currentLevel].append(tree.key)
    nextLevel = currentLevel + 1
    find_nodes_between_two_levels(tree.left, high, low, nextLevel, output)
    find_nodes_between_two_levels(tree.right, high, low, nextLevel, output)

    return output
```

Here is an output:

```
print find_nodes_between_two_levels(t2, 2, 4)
{2: [8, 22], 3: [4, 12], 4: [10, 14]}
```

What is the iterative solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since this function is not tail recursive, the iterative solution is going to require maintaining your own state either by a stack or a queue. Personally for this type of problem, I would probably use a queue approach and do a breadth-first walk of the tree.

```
def find_nodes_between_two_levels(root, high, low):
    from collections import defaultdict
    output = defaultdict(list)
    queue = [(root, 1)]
    while queue:
        tree, level = queue.pop()
        if not tree or level > low:
            continue
        if high <= level <= low:
            output[level].append(tree.key)
        level += 1
        queue.append((tree.left, level))
        queue.append((tree.right, level))
    return output
```

I left your original meaning of `high` and `low`, but these are somewhat confusing since `high < low`.

The important part of this answer is to see how the recursive and iterative solutions are related. Structurally, they are very similar. The key observations are that instead of using an implicit stack to maintain state, the state is now being maintained in an explicit `queue`. Each previous recursive invocation now becomes an `append` invocation to the `queue`. The previous `output` argument can now become a local variable since there are no recursive calls to track state across. Likewise, the `high` and `low` arguments do not need to be maintained since they are immutable across the recursive invocations.

Comment: Thanks a lot b4hand! Especially for the explanation how replacing implicit stack with explicit queue can turn this into iterative solution.

Comment: @user3390764 if only there were some way to [objectively show appreciation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) on StackOverflow.